# Unable to find module 'server', added express to Ember-Cli app

Tags: express, ember.js, ember-cli

I've added an expressJS app inside my ember app so I can provide a backend API for my ember app.

**My process:**

```
npm install express --save
```

I created a folder called "server" in the route of my ember application and inside that a file called "server.js".

Yesterday I had it working fine, I already had my ember app running via `ember s` and tested out the express app using `nodemon server/server.js` and checking the endpoints I created with Postman.

However this morning when I've tried to run `ember s` I'm given the following error:

```
C:\Sandbox\tsodash>ember s
version: 2.3.0-beta.2
Cannot find module 'C:\Sandbox\tsodash\server'
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Sandbox\tsodash\server'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Project.require (C:\Sandbox\tsodash\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\project.js:281:12)
    at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.processAppMiddlewares (C:\Sandbox\tsodash\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\tasks\server\express-server.js:115:33)
    at Class.<anonymous> (C:\Sandbox\tsodash\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\tasks\server\express-server.js:220:21)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (C:\Sandbox\tsodash\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1036:16)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (C:\Sandbox\tsodash\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1048:17)
    at C:\Sandbox\tsodash\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:331:11
```

Naturally I assumed I just needed to use `modules.exports = function(){ //..expressjs code}`

**Full Code**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var request = require('request');
var btoa = require('btoa');
var config = require('./config');
var _ = require('lodash');


module.exports = function(){

  var endPoints = config.endPoints;
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  }));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());

  var port = process.env.PORT || 4200;

  var router = express.Router();

  // middleware to use for all requests
  router.use(function (req, res, next) {
    // do logging
    console.log('Something is happening.');
    next(); // make sure we go to the next routes and don't stop here
  });


  router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.json({
      message: 'TSO Git Dash'
    });
  });

  //  ..      
  app.use('/api', router);

  app.listen(port);
  console.log('Magic happens on port: ' + port);
}
```

Still no avail.

Folder structure:

[image: Folder structure]

Any ideas? I'm assuming it's something simple that I've missed. But I'm stumped.

Comment: Can you see if it will run if you move `models` folder somewhere else?

Comment: I moved it elsewhere, I even deleted it (not currently using the models) and still no success.

Comment: Have you checked out [ember-cli-mirage](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/)? It's a great solution if you want to mock out an API for your Ember application.

Comment: I have indeed! The thing is I'm actually developing my API at the minute.

Comment: Ember CLI already comes with an express server to serve up the app, so the error might be related with http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#mocks-and-fixtures ?

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I'll try a few things tonight and report any success / issues. Thanks @locks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @locks suggested in the comments, there is an express server used in [mocks and fixtures](http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#mocks-and-fixtures). The fix was simple, I renamed the folder and the JS file to "api" and ran `ember s` and it worked perfectly. It seems to have been a naming conflict.